# Update only date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Table name: **tasklist**

```
|start_time                |end_time                  |task_duration  |
 __________________________ __________________________ _______________
|2001-01-01 17:24:50.000000|2014-02-04 10:04:10.000000|00:14:53.000000|
|2013-08-31 10:53:09.000000|2013-09-19 11:16:54.000000|00:21:19.000000|
|2013-08-31 18:30:28.000000|2013-10-07 18:43:55.000000|00:13:17.000000|
```

I have to change date part of start_time to end_time columns retaining the time values as I need it for task_duration column. I used this query to get this

```
SELECT * FROM `tasklist` WHERE (DATEDIFF(`end_time`,`start_time`)> 1)
```

Comment: The task duration values are wrong in this, but difference of end_time and start_time will be in task_duration coloumns

Comment: I have to put the same date as that in end_time in start_time for over 2000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = DATEADD(MONTH,1,YourColumn) 
WHERE YourColumn = '20120410 08:03:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).
For example, lets say that you want to add 30 days to the current starttime data. You can achieve the same using the following syntax:

```
UPDATE tasklist SET starttime = DATE_ADD(starttime, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Hope this helps!

The link provided at the top of this answer contains plenty examples which can help you understand the operations.